# Python: How to read multiple spreadsheets into a new format in a CSV?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, csv, openpyxl, xlrd

I (newcomer) try to read from an excel document several tables and read in a new format in a single csv.
In the csv, i need the following fields: year (from a global variable), month (from a global variable), outlet (name of the tablesheet); rowvalue [a] (string to explain the row), columnvalue [1] (string to explain the cloumn), cellvalue (float)

The corresponding values must then be entered in these.

From the respective tables, only RowNum 6 to 89 need to be read

```
#BWA-Reader
#read the excel spreadsheet with all sheets
#Python 3.6

Importe
import openpyxl
import xlrd
from PIL import Image as PILImage
import csv

# year value of the Business analysis
year = "2018"

# month value of the Business analysis
month = "11"

# .xlxs path
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("BWA Zusammenfassung 18-11.xlsx")
print("Found your Spreadsheet")
# List of sheets
sheets = wb.get_sheet_names()

# remove unneccessary sheets
list_to_remove = ("P",'APn','AP')
sheets_clean = list(set(sheets).difference(set(list_to_remove)))
print("sheets to load: " + str(sheets_clean))

# for loop for every sheet based on sheets_clean
for sheet in sheets_clean:

# for loop to build list for row and cell value
    all_rows = []
    for row in wb[sheet].rows:
        current_row = []
        for cell in row:
            current_row.append (cell.value)
        all_rows.append(current_row)
        print(all_rows)
# i´m stucked -.-´
```

I expect an output like:

```
2018;11;Oldenburg;total_sales;monthly;145840.00
```

all sheets in one csv

Thank you so much for every idea how to solve my project!

Comment: What output is it currently generating?

Comment: Hey, i get a list of each row from each table. this is where i stuck. i don't find the right answer to transform the values of the hundred lists into my needed csv format:  [142, 'Fremdmieten', 165, None, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, None, 0, 1448.7, None, 0.07, 0.03388769028363356, 0, 0, 0, None, 0, None, 165, None, 0.01]

Comment: The values stands for: id,id_name,monthly_values,empty,percentage_monthly_values,monthly_budget,perecentage_monthly_budget,empty, accumulated_value,empty,percentage_ accumulated_value,benchmark, accumulated_budget_value,percentage_ accumulated_budget, accumulated_lastyear_value,empty,percentage_ accumulated _lastyear_total_value,empty,percentage_lastyear_total_value

Comment: Use the `csv` module and write a line as you read the row from the Excel file.

Comment: hey charlie, maybe i act total stupid, but can you give me a hint for the code? This would solve one of my  problems on the road to the solution

Answer (score 0):

The complete answer to this question is very dependent on the actual dataset.

I would recommend looking into pandas' [`read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) function. This will make it so much easier to extract the needed rows/columns/cells, all without looping through all of the sheets.

You might need some tutorials on pandas in order to get there, but judging by what you are trying to do, pandas might be a useful skill to have in the future!